# Is there a way to get the value from a reference type?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to move selected items from one list to another.

This code doesn't work because "itemsToMove" is a reference type and is not holding the value but instead a reference to that list.
so when i change the list i get an enumerable exception.

```
       Dim itemsToMove = FullList.SelectedItems()
        For Each item As Object In itemsToMove
            GroupList.Items.Add(item)
            FullList.Items.Remove(item)
        Next
```

Is there a way to tell "itemsTomove" to take the Value of  FullList.SelectedItems() instead of a reference to the memory? basically clone that list?

i did some research and i found some terms such as Boxing and Un-boxing but i do not really know if that is relevant.

If i cannot do that, does that mean This is the only (cleanest) way to do what i want?

```
        Dim itemsToMove As Collection = New Collection()
        For Each i As Object In FullList.SelectedItems()
            itemsToMove.Add(i)
        Next


        For Each item As Object In itemsToMove
            GroupList.Items.Add(item)
            FullList.Items.Remove(item)
        Next
```

Comment: Why have you tagged C# here?

Comment: Also, don't tell us to "imagine" what `itemsTomove`, give us the actual type that it is. And give us the full error message or we have to guess at what the problem is.

Comment: Boxing and unboxing are not relevant here.  They related specifically to value types, where boxing is the act of getting an `Object` reference to a value and unboxing is the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a copy of a reference type then it is up to you to create, yes.  In this particular case, you wouldn't do it like you showed though.  You can just do this:

```
For Each selectedItem In FullList.SelectedItems.Cast(Of Object)().ToArray()
    FullList.Items.Remove(selectedItem)
    GroupList.Items.Add(selectedItem)
Next
```

The `ToArray` method is quick way to create an array from an `IEnumerable(Of T)` and `Cast(Of T)` creates an `IEnumerable(Of T)` from an `IEnumerable`.  In this case, as both the source and the target don't care about the specific type, you can just use `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use AddRange and Clear methods
This exemple below is in c#

https://dotnetfiddle.net/USSfte

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
    private static List<String> _data = new List<String>();
    private static void GenerateFakeData(){
        _data.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select((e) => String.Format("fake_{0}",e)));
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        GenerateFakeData();
        List<string> GroupList= new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine("Before\t\tGroupList.Count:{0}\t_data.Count:{1}",GroupList.Count(),_data.Count());     
        GroupList = new List<String>();
        var FullList = SelectedItems();

        /*AddRange*/
        GroupList.AddRange(FullList);
        /*Clear*/
        FullList.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("After\t\tGroupList.Count:{0}\t_data.Count:{1}",GroupList.Count(),_data.Count());

    }

    public static  IList<String> SelectedItems(){
        return _data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't post links to code. If you have some actual working code, put it in your answer. If the dotnetfiddle site goes away, this answer becomes meaningless.